# Nativescript navigation to same page

Tags: javascript, nativescript

How to navigate from current page to same page to get animation of sliding, currently if i navigate to same page using frame module then it doesn't show any animations it simply updates the content of the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your scenario and the page transitions should be executed as expected while navigating to the current page on the same way it is done while it is made for a different one. 
I am attaching sample code. 
XML

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo" class="page">

    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="My App" icon="" class="action-bar">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>

    <StackLayout class="p-20">
        <Label text="Tap the button" class="h1 text-center"/>
        <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-active"/>
        <Label text="{{ message }}" class="h2 text-center" textWrap="true"/>
        <Button text="Navigate" tap="onTap2" class="btn btn-primary btn-active"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

TypeScript

```
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { HelloWorldModel } from './main-view-model';
import {topmost} from "ui/frame"

export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {

    let page = <Page>args.object;


    page.bindingContext = new HelloWorldModel();
}

export function onTap2(args){
    var navigationEntry = {
        moduleName: "main-page",
        animated: true,
        clearHistory:true,
        transition: {
            name: "slide",
            duration: 380,
            curve: "easeIn"
        }
    };
    topmost().navigate(navigationEntry);
}
```

In the project, I am also using `clearHistory`, which prevents saving the navigation in the app history.

Comment: is your above typescript file is main-page.ts? If yes then does it showing animation of sliding?

Comment: indeed the above-attached code is from main-page.ts file and the transition works as expected while navigating

Comment: Yeah its working in mine now, And don't know what was the error and thanks :)